# Convert date column to character column

Tags: sql, database, sas

One of the columns is present in date datatype. I need to convert that date column in character datatype so that it can be concatenated with another character column.
Right now my date column is present in the following format : 09-JUN-2020.

Please help me in converting this column to character column.This needs to be done sas enterprise guide.

Thank u so much in advance.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/How-to-convert-datetime-to-string-date-in-SAS-Enterprise-guide-6/td-p/294191

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAS numeric to character conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109194/sas-numeric-to-character-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PUT() to convert from numeric to character. You need to find the format you want the output to look like and use that as your second parameter. Assuming you want your date to look like 2020-06-02 character this works:

```
*puts date as 2020-06-02;
newVar1 = put(dateVar, yymmddd10.);

*creates date variable as 02Jun2020;
newVar2 = put(dateVar, date9.);
```

FYI - [You can find the list of formats available here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n0p2fmevfgj470n17h4k9f27qjag.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)